# How to make an array in database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I create an a array of wordsParasits in firebase:

```
   set(ref(db, 'users/' + res.data.localId), {          
            ArrOfParasites: [],
}
```

How can i update it?
If i try like this, it doesn't work:

```
  update(ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId), {       
    ArrOfParasites: filteredArr.push()
// if i try this, outpi looks like: ArrOfParasites : 4 
}
```

Filtered array looks like:

```
[["блин", 1], ["допустим", 1], ["фактически", 1], ["получается", 1]]
```

I need to update all array in firebase db

Comment: Try  this: `db.collection("users").doc(localId).update({ArrOfParasites: filteredArr.push()});` Also instead of saying "doesn't work" can you specify the error?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: if i try my mtrhod i take an a number: ArrOfParasites
:
4

Comment: But i need an a array of words